# Eclipse: Text search all files in Maven dependencies

Tags: eclipse

I am looking to search all XML files on my application's classpath in Eclipse.

My application's classpath is defined by all the Maven dependencies it imports.

I am aware I can do a CTRL-SHIFT-T to search by Java types within Maven dependencies.

However, how can I search through non-Java types such as XMLs etc?

Comment: Do you want to search the content of the files?

Comment: Yes that is what I was hoping to do